# vagrant上でheroku openが出来ないです

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, vagrant

Vagrantで、CentOSを導入し、ruby on railsの開発環境を構築しました。

herokuをインストール後、

```
git push heroku master
```

で、Herokuにリポジトリをプッシュし、

```
heroku open
```

を打つと以下のエラーが出ます。

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 sample]$ heroku open
Opening peaceful-bayou-2427... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Unable to find a browser command. If this is unexpected, Please rerun with environment variable LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true or the '-d' commandline option and file a bug at https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/new (Launchy::CommandNotFoundError)
    Command:     heroku open
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.42.15 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.0.0
    Error ID:    c716dec578b84cc4805fea546d15328b


    More information in /home/vagrant/.heroku/error.log
```

色々原因を調べてみたのですが、結局解決できず困っています。。

どうすればいいのかご存知の方、教えていただきたいです。 
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`/home/vagrant/.heroku/error.log`も見た方が確実ですがブラウザが見つけられないようですね。
(同じ環境が手元に無いため、以下はすべて推測になります)

herokuコマンドが使うブラウザは環境変数`BROWSER`で変更できるらしいので、例えばFirefoxを使うならば、

```sh
BROWSER=firefox heroku open
```

と実行するか、あらかじめ

```sh
export BROWSER=firefox
```

のように設定しておけばよいはずです。

しかし、開発用の仮想環境にはGUIのブラウザなどインストールしていないかもしれません。
その場合w3m, lynx, wget, curlなどのツールを利用する手もありますが、あきらめてホスト側で閲覧するのが快適でしょう。
下記のように`BROWSER`を`echo`にしておけば`heroku open`でURLが出力されると思うので、それを普段利用しているブラウザで開けばよいのではないでしょうか。

```sh
BROWSER=echo heroku open
```